# How to reverse positive lookbehind(?<=) in regexp?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

When I use:

```
String s = "http://google.com, /home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/META-INF/plugin.xml"
ArrayList<String> ms = s.findAll(/(?<=\/)\/\S+/)
println(ms)
```

The output is:

```
[/google.com,]
```

When I change to:

```
s.findAll(/(?<!\/)\/\S+/)
```

The output is:

```
[//google.com,, /home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/META-INF/plugin.xml]
```

In my understanding, `/(?<!\/)\/\S+/` output should be same as `/(?<=\b)\/\S+/` output but in fact it's not. Why?

Comment: What do you need to get? `/(?<!\/)\/\S+/` != `/(?<=\b)\/\S+/` because the `\b` is a word boundary, you require a word letter before `/`. `(?<!\/)` fails a match if there is a `/` before `/`.

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding your question.* Result can not be same. Look:

`(?<!/)/\S+` means `find the place where "/" standing before "/" and give me this "/" with all non-whitespace character after it`. There is just one place.

Result will be: `/google.com,`

There is no other places in your string where `"/"` character stands before `"/"`

---

`(?<=\b)\/\S+` means `find the place where word boundary standing before "/" and give me this "/" and all non-whitespace character after it`.

Result will be: `/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-idea/META-INF/plugin.xml`

In this case letter `"e"` of word `"home"` and character `"/"` himself will be recognized as word boundary.

---

*Just fore reference:*

`(?<=)` is positive look-behind. It checks, what immediately precedes the current position in string. For example:

`(?<=foo)bar` means `select 'bar', if 'foo' standing before`

`(?<!)` is negative look-behind. It check, what immediately *does not* precedes the current position. For example:

`(?<!foo)bar` means `select 'bar', if 'foo' does NOT standing before`

`\b` means word boundary. It matches positions where one side is a word character and the other side is not a word. For example:

`(?<=\b)bar` means `select 'bar', if word boundary standing before`
Search in `"foo bar"` string will return `"bar"` because of space between words. But `"foobar"` will return nothing, because there is no space between word in last string, so there is no word boundary before `"bar"`.

Comment: Is [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) not enough to explain what a regex mean? Your answer does not help at all. At least because we do not know what OP needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm so sorry my answer did not help for you personally. I replied, as I understand the question.

Comment: No, @WiktorStribiżew is correct, this answer is just a collection of general information; it does nothing to address the actual question.

Comment: @AlanMoore, probably you have not noticed, but I didn't say, that WiktorStribiżew is not correct. And I apologized.

Answer (score 0):

`\/\S+` will match `//google.com`, so `(?<!\/)` is meaningless